# Returning an integer value from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have an SQL query as follows:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id FROM Pages WHERE pageName=about",conn);
//cmd.Parameters.Add("@pageName","hakkinda");

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

flID = reader.GetInt16(0);

reader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

I get an error message:

`Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.`

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice a couple potential issues:

You need to call reader.Read(), before trying to read data from it.  This is usually done in a loop when people expect multiple rows.

```
while (reader.Read()) {
    flID = reader.GetInt16(0);
}
```

also in your SQL if "about" is meant to be a literal and not another column name you probably need single quotes around it:

```
"SELECT id FROM Pages WHERE pageName='about'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning 0 results. This is because the parameter value in the SQL string is missing quotes. It should read as follows (notice the single quotes around the word 'about'):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id FROM Pages WHERE pageName='about'",conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `DataReader.Read` to fetch the result:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
```

`DataReader.Read` returns a boolean, so if you have more than 1 result, you can do:

```
while (reader.Read()) {
  // read data here
}
```

Your select statement should be:

```
"SELECT id FROM Pages WHERE pageName='about'"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect only single value to be returned, you can use **.ExecuteScalar()**

```
flID = int.Parse(query.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Also, use single quotation marks for pageName value.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id FROM Pages WHERE pageName='about';",conn);
```